# Setting combobox selected item colour in xaml app

Tags: xaml

I've got some fairly specific formatting requirements for a combobox in a xaml app. Mostly, it's just colours, although I've had to specify a template in order to change the dropdown arrow glyph. I've set the Template, ItemTemplate and ItemsPanel Property, just with the specificed versions from MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709912.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709911.aspx.

I've set the colours as follows:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#fcffff" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxArrowPressedForegroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#fcffff" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxBackgroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#03233a" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#03233a" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#03233a" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPopupBackgroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#fcffff" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPopupForegroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#03233a" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#00a2ff" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush"
                     Color="#00a2ff" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#ffffff" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush"
                     Color="#00a2ff" />
```

However, whatever I do, the colour of the selected item won't change from the default. I suspect I've perhaps wrongly specified the ItemTemplate property; in the template as specified by MS, we have an ItemPresenter, and I wonder if this is somehow overriding my specified ItemTemplate. Can anyone help?

Comment: Share any templates related that you're using that are not the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

All templates are the defaults as given in the links - but resolved by re-pasting the template, it must have got messed up somewhere. Thanks for the responses!